# Why does UIImageView appear to be partially transparent

Tags: iphone, uiimageview

I have a simple app that just displays a UIImageView.  For some reason the image appears that it is partially transparent as it is much lighter than if I view the same image in photoshop.  Any suggestions...I though by default a UIView is opaque.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have probably changed the alpha of your imageView or the view itself. check for the the transparency of your imageview also. Because the default alpha of the imageview is 1 and opacity is also set to 100%. You might have chane one of these otherwise this is the problem of your image only

Comment: silly me... I was viewing the original image in ColorSync and this program increased the contrast, the iPhone had it right... so you are right Madhup... it was the image

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that UIImageView is by default partially transparent? Try changing the background colour of the application and see if that affects the outcome of your image, if it is transparent it should be darker with a black background rather than white.